# Отбор 5 элементов из списка в соответствии с условиями

Tags: python, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Нужно из списка (порядка `100` элементов)  с элементами вида

`{'name': 'Аня', 'price': 9.5, 'score': 2.1}`

получить список `5` элементов с максимально возможной суммой значений `'score'` этих элементов при условии, что сумма значений `'price'` этих элементов не превышает определенной величины. Пробовал так:

```
from itertools import combinations

# players - заданный список
result = combinations(players, 5)
```

После чего итерировал `result` и  фильтровал согласно условиям. Этот способ мне не подошел, т.к. миллионы комбинаций перебираются очень долго.

Пробовал так:

```
result = []
max_score = 0
for i1 in players[:-4]:
  if i1['price'] > budget:
    continue
  for i2 in players[players.index(i1)+1:-3]:
    if i1['price'] + i2['price']> budget:
      continue
    for i3 in players[players.index(i2)+1:-2]:
      if i1['price'] + i2['price'] + i3['price'] > budget:
        continue
      for i4 in players[players.index(i3)+1:-1]:
        if i1['price'] + i2['price'] + i3['price'] + i4['price'] > budget:
          continue
        for i5 in players[players.index(i4)+1:]:
          if i1['price'] + i2['price'] + i3['price'] + i4['price'] + i5['price'] > budget:
            continue
          elif i1['score'] + i2['score'] + i3['score'] + i4['score'] + i5['score'] > max_score:
            max_score = i1['score'] + i2['score'] + i3['score'] + i4['score'] + i5['score']
            result= [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5]
```

Этот способ тоже очень медленный.
Как еще можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Что означает сумма значений?

Comment: @Alban i1['score'] + i2['score'] + i3['score'] + i4['score'] + i5['score'] Сумма значений ключей 'score'

Comment: А причем тут комбинации?

Comment: Вообще, вроде, типичное дискретное программирование, максимизация линейного функционала в вершинах единичного куба при двух линейных ограничениях.

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5 В сети много вариантов решения этой задачи на разных ЯП, включая Python